# How can I have different pages/views.cshtml rendering unique components/directives?

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-5, episerver

Does anyone have any experience with getting Angular 8 working on a MPA?

It seems like all the components have to live inside the  tags and then the template of that component has to render other components.

I'm working on a MVC5 app and what I'm after is having different pages/views.cshtml rendering unique components/directives.

This was easily achieved with AngularJs as everything lived inside the 
"ng-app"

My thinking is that in the _master.cshtml file I should be able to do 
something like this:

```
<app-root>
    @RenderBody()
</app-root>

then in index1.cshtml

<my-component-1></my-component-1>

index2.cshtml

<my-componet-2></mycomponet-2>
```

and so on but so far I haven't found anything helpful apart form this reddit post from 3 years ago.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/424nwn/using_angular_2_without_it_being_a_single_page_app/

But the answer seems outdated as things have changed since Angular2.

Comment: I'm curious - what's the goal in using Angular8 in the first place?  Why not all-MVC5?  Or all-Angular8 (for the client-side app), and just a REST service for the back-end?

Comment: We are using episerver a CMS tool that generates custom content built with MVC5. We have lots of widgets made with angularjs that we currently use. I've been asked to upgrade to the new angular (not js) to future proof our project.

Comment: Depending on what these widgets do - maybe the best "future proofing" might be to adopt a different widget framework (like Kendo UI, or Bootstrap).  For example, look here: https://uxplanet.org/top-15-free-bootstrap-ui-kits-for-2019-to-help-you-work-smarter-47dc467b30da

Answer (score 1):

You could render the whole site on the client-side and set up the routing to work with Episerver using the ContentDeliveryAPI addon. That way you only need one page template, one block template, and a master page (instead of multiple .cshtml files with empty boilerplate). For example:

[Shared/_BaseLayout.cshtml](https://github.com/episerver/musicfestival-vue-template/blob/master/src/MusicFestival.Vue.Template/Views/Shared/_BaseLayout.cshtml)

```
<body>
    <div class="Page" id="App">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @Html.RenderEPiServerQuickNavigator()
    <script src="~/Assets/bundled/main.bundle.js"></script>
    @Html.RequiredClientResources("Footer")
</body>
```

[DefaultPage/Index.cshtml](https://github.com/episerver/musicfestival-vue-template/blob/master/src/MusicFestival.Vue.Template/Views/DefaultPage/Index.cshtml)

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_BaseLayout.cshtml";
}

<default-page></default-page>
```

[components/DefaultPage.vue](https://github.com/episerver/musicfestival-vue-template/blob/master/src/MusicFestival.Vue.Template/Assets/Scripts/components/DefaultPage.vue)

```
<div class="DefaultPage">
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

`router-view` is the Vue component for what the routing should render. I imagine it's the same as Angular's `router-outlet` ([docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-outlet)). The magic happens in the router, in combination with a page component selector, which you can read more about in [this blog post](https://world.episerver.com/blogs/Nicklas-Israelsson/Dates/2018/10/routing-in-a-spa-with-a-working-on-page-editing-experience-cms-ui-11-11-0/).

[components/PageComponentSelector.vue](https://github.com/episerver/musicfestival-vue-template/blob/master/src/MusicFestival.Vue.Template/Assets/Scripts/components/PageComponentSelector.vue)

```
<div v-if="modelLoaded">
    <component :is="getComponentTypeForPage(model)" :model="model"></component>
</div>
```

`component` is a Vue component that renders a component with the name given in the `is` attribute. I'm sure there's something similar in Angular.

Take a look at our reference SPA site. It's in Vue but the concepts should be easy to use in any client-side framework. Read more in the [blog series explaining the concepts](https://world.episerver.com/blogs/john-philip-johansson/dates/2018/10/introducing-a-new-template-site-for-spas-musicfestival/) and take a look at the [open source code on github](https://github.com/episerver/musicfestival-vue-template).